# What's the point of cylon.js if you have to keep the Arduino connected by wire?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

Perhaps this question is too vague:  I am running some tests with Cylon.js, a javascript library that can control an arduino board with node.js

It works, but somehow I expected it to keep working when disconnecting the serial cable. I was under the impression that Cylon.js (or Johnny-five.js) would enable you to write Arduino code in javascript.

What's the point of "controlling" an arduino from javascript, if it has to remain connected to a laptop?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is an interpreted language with a syntax many developers prefer to use, it has nothing to do with remote development. You should be able to craft up something on your own using sockets, or there maybe something previously written available.

Many developers love using a single syntax for all of their projects, and many new projects are continually adding frameworks or wrappers for Node so the same JavaScript syntax can also be used regardless of scenario.

This allows for more robust and efficient code, as you only need to remember a single languages modules, function names, syntax and overrides, ultimately becoming more proficient in the language as an entirety.

Comment: OK, but my question is not why you would want to use javascript :) (perhaps my wording is too vague). I was just wondering why you would use cylon.js to control an arduino, if that means that the arduino has to remain tethered to a laptop. (most arduino projects can stand on their own which makes them more useful in my opinion).